# Homotopy involving a disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am in some trouble to solve a problem about homotopies. Suppose that $f$ an injective a map which sends the unit sphere $S^1$ into a punctued disk (with an interior point removed). Assume that the map $g$ sends the unit sphere to a constant point.

I have to show that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic. I don't see how to construct an explicit homotopy...